# pushViewController from presentView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

rootVC -> present LoginVC -> pushViewControllers SignUpVC or FindPasswordVC (it depends on which button is tapped on LoginVC)

The way I did is

1. present LoginVC on rootVC
2. dismiss LoginVC after tapping the button and send selectedData to rootVC
3. pushViewControllers SignUpVC or FindPasswordVC from rootVC

But I want to **move directly to SignUpVC or FindPasswordVC from LoginVC with navigationbar and shoulb be based on rootVC's navigation**. 
Also LoginVC must be shown as present modal. 
Is it possible? if it's possible then how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed `LoginVC`  inside a navigation controller and show it modally then inside of it do the pushes after finish dismiss it with

```
 self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
```

and that will return you back to the root again

Comment: Is it possible to do this with rootVC'navigation?

Comment: no because this will need `LoginVC ` being not modally presented meaning all vcs to be pushed

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but I wanted to know clearly it's really impossible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible... what you have to do is to present modally `Navigation Controller` whose root controller is `LoginVC` .. Then you can use push

Comment: I need to use rootVC's navigation. not new navigation...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by associating a target object and an action method.

```
signUpButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(navigateTo), for: .touchUpInside)


@objc func navigateTo() {
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SignUpVC(), animated: true)
}
```